# Google Analytics gtag code messes up woocommerce cart & login

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, google-analytics

I'm having this issue where this code provided by google analytics gtag, added with either `wp_head()` or `wp_footer()` or a GA plugin:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXXX"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXXX');
</script>
```

Messes up the cart & login.

**For login, this happens**:

- users logs in, refreshes to same page with login prompt, log again and you're in after second attempt. Click on any menu and login prompt again. Do this login (third) and you seem to be setup. This happens every time I log out and try to login again.

**For cart, this happens**:

- First item added to cart, minicart is ok (displays 1 item), but cart displays no items. If another item is added then it's ok, otherwise a couple of refreshes and in 1-2 mins the item is added. After that it's ok.

The reason I know it's GA it's because I spent about 4hrs debugging and the only cause for this weird and uncomfortable bug seems to be this solely script, in form of manual setup or plugin (all plugins and code snippets but woocommerce & woocommerce services disabled).

Using analytics.js tag solved the issue but I'd like to use the new code (gtag, for no particular reason but to keep up).

Any advice?

There is no console error.

Comment: If it's taking over a minute for the first item to be added to the cart then it sounds like the script is delaying further activity.  Is that how you're including the script (as shown in your sample above) or are you enqueuing it?

Comment: Hi @TonyDjukic. I updated the question is not that the item keeps trying to be added to cart. It's added (minicart is ok) but then I got nothing on the cart page. I'm adding the code with wp_head() or wp_footer() both same results

Comment: Are you enqueuing the script or printing to the wp_head/wp_footer?